# c programming - directory name from DIR* struct

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dirent.h

from [dirent.h](https://github.com/tronkko/dirent/blob/master/include/dirent.h) we can see that DIR struct is

```
struct DIR {
    struct dirent ent;
    struct _WDIR *wdirp;
};
```

and **dirent** struct is

```
struct dirent {
    /* Always zero */
    long d_ino;

    /* File position within stream */
    long d_off;

    /* Structure size */
    unsigned short d_reclen;

    /* Length of name without \0 */
    size_t d_namlen;

    /* File type */
    int d_type;

    /* File name */
    char d_name[PATH_MAX+1];
};
```

My question is: If we have only DIR * struct -let say **dir** -and from this struct we want to extract directory name, normally we -should? - do:

```
const char * dirname = dir->ent.d_name;
```

however this not compile, error is:

```
dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Thanks

Comment: These are exposed implementation details which you are not supposed to access directly. Also, the contents of the embedded `dirent` do _not_ identify the directory whose name was passed to `opendir`; they are scratch storage used by `readdir`, IIRC.  Can you please give more detail about what you are trying to do - where you got this `DIR` from, why you think you need to "extract directory name" from it, etc.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't be accessing the contents of a `DIR` directly.

To iterate through the entries in a directory, you need to call `readdir`, passing it a `DIR *` that was returned from `opendir`.  This will return a `dirent *` from which you can read the name of the directory entry.

The function will return `NULL` when all entries have been read.